# Pass in queried data from another array into a construction of component array using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have an array of objects with the form called pairIDCost

```
{"id": 1, cost: "10"}
```

And I want to pass the cost value into each component in the component array constructed from another array (array1) that looks something like this

```
const componentArray = array1.map(d => <Component cost={QUERIED_COST} data={...} />)
```

Instead of passing the entire array of objects into each component of the component list and doing the logic in the child component, I figured it would be more efficient to first query for the correct cost of each component.

I tried to pass a mess of nested function in place of QUERIED_COST so the inside of the .map function looks like

```
d => <Component cost={ 
                       () => {
                                const tmp = pairIDCost.find(element => element.id === d.array)
                                return tmp.cost
                             }
                     }
```

What is the proper way to go around this? Does this "optimization" even matter when running apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should query the value before passing it to each component. The way you suggest passes a function as prop to the child component, which is incorrect. Instead, do it inside the map loop:

```
const componentArray = array1.map(d => {
       const tmp = pairIDCost.find(element => element.id === d.array);
       return <Component cost={tmp && tmp.cost} data={...} />
   });
```